# В Pyqt5 не видно кнопки за методом

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Я новичок, не очень пока разбираюсь во всем этом, так что если не будет какой-то нужной информации для вас, извините. 
Кнопка (`quadratic`) да и не только она определена в методе, а за ним к ней обратиться нельзя.

```
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 700)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2E4172")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.quadratic = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)

    def choice(self):  # choice btn's
        self.quadratic.clicked.connect(lambda: self.output_qua())
        self.linear.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_dif())
```

И вот такая ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'quadratic'.

Заранее спасибо

**Update:**

Пример

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.click_event()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 180, 221, 111))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def click_event(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.f())

    def f(self):
        self.pushButton.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
# ???    def __init__(self):
# ???        self.click_event()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 180, 221, 111))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)  
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.pushButton.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В инит же только один раз сработает? Просто у меня 8 кнопок и 3 из них уравнения выводят. А когда я сделал Вашим способом, то если я кликаю только на одну то все ок, а когда нажимаю на вторую она один раз отрабатывает и больше кнопки не работают

Comment: @Андрей, в ответе нет никаких моих способов. Я только сделал чтобы пример, который вы привели - работал. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте НОВЫЙ вопрос.

Comment: @Андрей вы ответ нормально прочитайте, что вам словами сказали, а потом уже копируйте и разбирайте скрипт.